# Validate depending fields with bootstrapValidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

i need to validate a input field that depends on a selection in a dropdown.

If nothing is selected in dropdown, user must fill input! And vice versa.

I can't find anything on http://formvalidation.io/

I wil be glad about some help.

Comment: What environment are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Within this http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB06R48S4
Is this what you want to know?

Comment: Cool site.  However, what language are you programming in and on what type of server?

Comment: PHP, but the validation is in JS. Server is a local xampp.